# Is there a function in Rhapsody java api to know the relationship between features?

Tags: java, relationship, rhapsody

I want to find out if a feature is a parent or a child to an other feature, either directly and indirectly.(In a composition)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you get handed an IRPRelation, that will have two methods that should be of interest:  getOtherClass() which will give you the class that is being composed and getOfClass() which will give you the class that is doing the composing.